Specified provider is not supported IBMDA400
A Microsoft SSIS (Sql Server Integration Service, as a dtsx file) was handed to me by a fellow co-worker, but when I open it in Visual Studio 2019 and try to edit one of its connections I get an error "specified provider is not supported". When I open the dtsx file in a text editor I can see it has, in various places "Provider=IBMDA400.Datasource.1". I think that is the one provider I'm missing. It connects to an AS/400 server but I seem to be missing the needed provider.
The question is this:
What package or software should I install to get the missing provider so I can run the mentioned service?
If you can please also tell me, where can I get that software or package?

You need to install two components (1) IBM I Access Client Solution (2) plus its Windows Application Package (separate install). Get these from your regular IBM channel (i.e from ACS download page, or via ESS) with an ibm-login-id, or from your colleagues (it is wise to use the same version as that used when creating and testing the dtsx file) so talk with the relevant devs.

@mao please put your comment as an answer so I can mark it as the answer, include the URL to the IBM ACS page. The windows application package I got it from the internet bouncing from site to site, ended in ACS. The IBM Access client I got it from my colleagues. Any way thank you.

This information is correct as of August 2024 but IBM may change things around  as time goes by, as is their annoying habit to continually break links and move things around and rename things for no reason.
You need to install two components, both of which you can download from the IBM ACS download link at this location:
https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/ibm-i-access-client-solutions
On that page, click the link "Downloads for IBM i Access Client Solutions", this will open an IBM login page. If you don't have an IBM login, you can make one of these from that page and then login.
After you login, it may ask you to tick "I agree" and "I confirm" to accept the license terms after clicking "View License".
The next screen lets you choose what to download. You need two separate packages, the first is "IBM i Access Client Solutions " (it will show the currently available version).  This delivers the IBM i access client, via a javascript installation tool.
Next you return to the downloads and click the download for "ACS Windows App Pkg English (64bit)". This delivers an installshield installation program (like a typical old style installation program) . The custom install lets you choose which bits to install, as some bits require payment while other parts do not.  It also puts a folder on your desktop for "IBM i access client solutions" and in there you see a folder "Programmer's Toolkit" that has links to the ".Net Provider Technical Reference" and "OLE DB Provider Technical Reference" and "Programmers Toolkit" ( which is collection of interlinked CHM files covering the different aspects of functionality and programming details for these). There are currently no PDF for this documentation. However, CHM viewers are available always on MS-Windows but also for Linux.
